# cannot get page source using c# httpwebrequest

Tags: c#

I tried to get the source of a particular site page using the code below but it failed.
I was able to get the page source in 1~2 seconds using a webbrowser or webdriver, but httpwebrequest failed.
I tried putting the actual webbrowser cookie into httpwebrequest, but it failed, too.
**(Exception - The operation has timed out)**

I wonder why it failed and want to learn through failure.
Thank you in advance!!.

```
string Html = String.Empty;
CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.coupang.com/");
req.Method = "GET";
req.Host = "www.coupang.com";
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36";
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3";
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
req.CookieContainer = cc;
using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
using (StreamReader str = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    Html = str.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `req.Host` from your code should do the trick.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.host?view=netframework-4.8):

> If the Host property is not set, then the Host header value to use in an HTTP request is based on the request URI.

You already set the URI in `(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.coupang.com/")` so I don't think doing it again is necessary.

**Result**

[image: Result]

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: I removed the req.Host, but failed to get the page source.

Comment: I added an image of my result. Try putting a breakpoint before `req.GetResponse()` and after. Actually there was a few times I get the timeout error. Is the site stable ?

Comment: The site is very stable. If you try to navigate to a real webBrowser, you can see that it is very stable.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But the problem has not been solved yet. (Exception - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.)

Comment: run it repeatedly, sometimes it succeeds once, but it mostly fails. In addition I have configured (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol). But it failed.